# jQuery create element with leading slash? $('</ul>')

Tags: jquery, dom

I just ran across a problem today where creating an element with a leading forward slash `$('</ul>')` caused a problem that was fixed by removing it `$('<ul>')`.

I have seen plenty of examples doing a leading slash (`$('</ul>')`), so what does it mean? I thought it just meant a self-contained element, kind of like shorthand for `<ul></ul>`.

Comment: That typically happens when someone doesn't understand how the DOM works, they're trying to add just a closing tag to an element, which won't work with elements in the DOM.

Comment: Using `$('</ul>')` will not cause jquery to create an element. Might as well just be `$()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it hard to believe that you've seen examples using a leading slash as that would only be a closing tag. It's far more likely that the examples you've seen use a trailing slash which combines an opening and closing tag to create an empty element:

```
$('<ul />');
```

The main difference here being that one is a valid declaration of an element whereas the the other is only half of the valid declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of a self closing tag such as `$('<ul />')`? The slash should be in the end.

As per the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — `$( "<img />" )` or `$( "<img>" )`, `$( "<a></a>" )` or `$( "<a>" )` — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript `createElement()` function.